# VSTO Addin Connecting to MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, vsto

I have a VSTO addin.  Right now I am hard coding two dictionaries for development.  They need to persist so I am going to use mssql.  I have created the tables and all, so everything is done on that end.  But I'm having some trouble getting a few things to work so I have a few questions:

First, is it possible to use Windows Forms in VSTO to create a CRUD form for the database tables?  There are 2 tables and they aren't too long.

Next, when connecting with SqlConnection, the example connection strings I am seeing don't make any sense. Here is an example: `tmpConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes");`  I'm not sure how to make the connection string.  Right now my db is a local mssql instance, but in the future it will be hosted on a local network server.  It says SQLEXPRESS now, is that the same as mssql?  If not how can I change it to mssql?  How do I construct the correct string for mssql and how do I authenticate?  Is it done in the connection string or somewhere else?

Next to Last, is there an easy way to query a database with 3 columns, ID (PK), domain, and dirname.  And place domain and dirname into a dict where domain is the key and dirname the value, the ID is uneeded for this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public void retrieveClient(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                  "SELECT ClientDirName, ClientEmailDomain FROM ClientTable;",
                  conn);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string clientDir = reader.GetString(0);
                        string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1);
                        clientDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No rows found in ClientTable", "Rows Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

And finally, the part where it says `string clientDir = reader.GetString(0)` and `string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1)`  Will it return the correct values here?  The table has 3 values as I said, ID, Dir, and Email.  But as you can see my SqlCommand only selects ClientDirName and ClientEmailDomain.  Does this mean the `GetString()` methods will return those with 0 and 1?  Or would it be 1 and 2 since ID is 0?  I'm not sure how it works,  does `reader.GetString()` base the indexes off the actual table or the SqlCommand?

I also wanted to know if the `while (reader.Read())` part will add each row one by one so that my `clientDict.Add()` would work properly or not.

If it possible to do CRUD with a database with windows forms please give me some guidance or a small example.  Other than that I just need my code examined to make sure it's doing what I want.  I've been trying to test it but there are a lot of other missing pieces at the moment so I need assistance.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.  And if someone could provide a few small example connection strings for both local and network mssql servers that require authentication it would be a huge help.  I've been looking everywhere and can't get this working.  I've heard EF could do it but I can't find a single example or guide that does what I need.  If someone could share one that may help too, if you with EF is the way to go.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can connect a vsto plugin to a database. See the Entity Framework if you want to speed up development. It lets you treat a table like a list of objects.

Comment: I tried to look into EF, but I can't find a guide that seems to work for me or has any examples pertaining to what I need.  Can you suggest anything?

Comment: What I'm asking for will completely solve my issue.  The  CRUD form is the least important but would be very nice to have and if it can only be done with entity framework, I'm willing to use that instead.

Comment: You can do it both ways. EF helps because you don't have to inline a bunch of sql and worry about connection issues once its setup. This is info on connection [mysql to EF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html) [This](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) is a good tutorial on EF. Just ignore everything that is specific to ASP and sub in the VSTO and you should be good.

Comment: Ill check it out, if any of you can elaborate a bit and provide some small examples and quick answers to my questions I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may treat your VSTO based add-in as a regular .Net application. There is no anything specific from the Db perspective. The only difference is that your VSTO assembly is run within the host application (not standalone). So, I'd suggest reading any good book on how to use SQL databases (ADO.NET) in .net applications or use EF (Entity Frameworks) first. It will give you the answer to all your questions.

Comment: Can you recommend any books or websites/tutorials?  The method I posted, is not EF correct?  Is there anything wrong with the code I posted?  Most of all, am I right about the indexes?  For `reader.GetString(index)` does index go by the table or by the sqlcommand I specified?  Meaning will 0 and 1 return ID and clientDirName or will it return clientDirName and clientEmailDomain when used with GetString(index)?  If you can answer that I will accept.